# How to style the bottom OS navigation bar in React Native / Expo?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation, react-navigation-v6

Sorry if the title wasn't very clear.

I'm using react navigation in an expo RN app.

Im not sure what this is called but Im referring to the bottom, OS gesture navigation here:

[image]

The background is all black. Whereas I would like it to behave like this example:

[image]

I realize the example picture contains tab navigator, but is there a way I can configure the gesture bar to hover over the background without one?

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: As of my knowledge you do not have control over the changing the background color of OS nav bar manually through React Navigation. It is handled by OS itself.